# Different status code for the same request in SoapUI and Spring Boot Java (or Postman) request

Tags: java, spring-boot, soap, soapui

I have this situation where I make a request to a SOAP service in SoapUI and the response is the expected result.

Then I go to Java (Spring Boot 2.7.3) and make the same request using POST method, sending the same XML and the payload and the proper headers (I suppose) but as response a get a 202 status code instead of 200.

Can anyone point anything wrong here?

This is the XML (same sent using SoapUI and using Java):

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:tot="http://www.totalbody.com/">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <tot:RealizarConsultaSQL>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <tot:codSentenca>Tech.001</tot:codSentenca>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <tot:codColigada>1</tot:codColigada>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <tot:codSistema>P</tot:codSistema>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <tot:parameters>CHAPA=01803-3</tot:parameters>
      </tot:RealizarConsultaSQL>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

And this is the java code to execute the same operation (I also have other SOAP services being requested the same way, and they work fine):

```
request = HttpRequest.newBuilder()                  
        .uri(new URI(this.soapTotvs))
        .header(TAG_CONTENT_TYPE, VALUE_CONTENT_TYPE_XML)                   
        .header("Authorization", getBasicAuthenticationHeader(username, password))
        .header("Accept", "application/xml")
        .POST(HttpRequest.BodyPublishers.ofString(xmlSoap))
        .version(HttpClient.Version.HTTP_2)
        .timeout(Duration.ofSeconds(1200))
        .build();

HttpClient client = HttpClient.newBuilder()
        .connectTimeout(Duration.ofSeconds(1200))
        .followRedirects(Redirect.NORMAL)                   
        .build();

CompletableFuture<HttpResponse<String>> responseFuture = client.sendAsync(request, HttpResponse.BodyHandlers.ofString());           
responseFuture.thenAccept(response -> {
    log.info("code.....: " + response.statusCode()); // always 202
    log.info("body.....: " + response.body()); // empty
    log.info("headers..: " + response.headers().map()); // {content-length=[0], date=[Tue, 07 Nov 2023 11:51:44 GMT], server=[Microsoft-HTTPAPI/2.0]}           
});                 
HttpResponse<String> result = responseFuture.join();
log.info("body returned..: " + result.body());
```

I´d appreciate any help here.

Comment: Hi, do you solved this problem? I'm the same problem here.